# Configure Node.js/Express server to use React-Router BrowserRouter

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router

In React Router v4, [the docs mention](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter) that the server needs to be specially configured to use the BrowserRouter. How would you configure your Node.js/Express server to work with the BrowswerRouter?

Comment: I am trying server rendering on node.js and having a similar issue `Invariant Violation: Browser history needs a DOM`. Any progress on your side?